# problema al crear un repositorio git

Tags: git, bitbucket, sourcetree

Tenemos un repositorio compartido en bitBucket con un compañero, lo que intentaba hacer es tratar de clonar ese repositorio, el problema es que siempre que trato me sale este error, tambien e probado crear uno nuevo pero el error persiste

```
git -c filter.lfs.smudge= -c filter.lfs.required=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks clone --branch master https://TomasDB@bitbucket.org/jpc1499/deliveryeat.git C:\Users\tdomi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PA
Cloning into 'C:\Users\tdomi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PA'...
fatal: invalid branch name: init.defaultBranch = 

Completed with errors, see above.
```

Comment: bitbucket? sourcetree? Podrías intentar editar tu pregunta y dar algo de contexto al mensaje de error?

Comment: Tenemos un repositorio compartido en bitBucket con un compañero, lo que intentaba hacer es tratar de clonar ese repositorio, el problema es que siempre que trato me sale este error, tambien e probado crear uno nuevo pero el error persiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde Git 2.28, no se asume más cuál es la rama por defecto (y te lo está diciendo en el mensaje de error). Antes se ponía por defecto *master* sin más.

Tienes que añadir a la configuración en tu instalación de Git (como cuando pones nombre e email):

```
$ git config --global init.defaultBranch [default_branch]
```

Y ya pondrás el nombre de la rama default en vez de [default_branch]. *development* suele ser una opción habitual.

Comment: Hola, perdón por no responder antes. Sii pude solucionar el problema con tu ayuda 

Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: @Tomas Súper! De eso se trata, me alegra que te sirviera. Recuerda que para que otros sepan que esto solucionó tu pregunta, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada haciendo clic en el tick verde a la izquierda. :)